# Flash builder and .Net integration using FluorineFx

Tags: .net, flex4, dataservice, fluorinefx

I'm trying to call a simple dataservice which is written in .Net from Flash builder 4. Please tell me the steps or else any links or samples. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use google?

Take a look at these, some of the links from the first page of results:

1. [official docs](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/index.html)
2. [here](http://blog.brainnovative.com/2009/11/fluorinefx-tutorial-integrate-net-with.html)
3. [or here](http://jimdonaghy.com/?p=11)

Seems like enough tutorial for me to do what you want.

p.s.
You can also use [WebOrb](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried Fluorine a couple years ago and I thought it sucked. Better is to create regular asp.net webservices (`.asmx`) and in the flex application use the [webservice class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdb.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf66651-7fee).

Another option is to use a dynamically or static xml-file that you read in flex.

Comment: FluorineFX is a great product, as is WebORB. The approach using asp.MVC returning JSON is also great. Using regular asp.net webservices is looking for problems.

Answer (score 0):

FluorineFX has some great examples shipped with the installation. WebORB also has great support, but it's not free + you don't get the source code.

On my blog you'll also find some good examples of using FluorineFX with Flex.

This post http://blog.johlero.eu/2011/11/12/invoking-restful-and-amf-services-from-flex-using-wcf-mvc-fluorinefx-in-net/ uses different approaches.